# Cannot obtain shape image from Overpass Turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-turbo

I wanted to export the graphical outline of a river in OpenStreetMap. I tried using the [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/#).

This is the script I used:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
nwr["name"="Mahaweli"]["waterway"="river"]({{bbox}});
out geom;
```

I get the map on the right side of the terminal:

[image]

But when I goto export it in the Export tab and click `png` I get a very off output.

How to fix that?

[image]

I would like to download the geoJSON or some sort of data format and fire it up in a GIS software, still this is not accurate enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the data as GeoJSON and use it as a layer in QGIS, like:

[image: Overpass data exported as GeoJSON over OpenTopoMap]

then export it as a png or whatever Project -> New Print Layout..